# Laravel 5 - Switch from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: php, http, laravel, https, laravel-5

I have recently created a laravel project, and I am facing issues with it since I am trying to get it setup with SSL (Cloudflare).

What is the best way to redirect the user to the secured enviroment correctly in laravel 5?

Also, my CSS and JS are not beeing loaded in due to the fact that http is not allowed and my browser blocks the files from beeing loaded because they could be potential harmfull. (Which is not the case though, to be clear)

Can someone get me off the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting your site users to a secure url (https://) should NOT be the job of the framework. This type of behavior should be handled on the DNS and A record level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that makes things clearer. Do you also know about the assets() function in laravel not doing https in front of the scripts?

Comment: @DennisSmink `asset()` will use HTTPS on a HTTPS page, but it relies on `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` being set properly I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS should be handled by the webserver.

Your assets are probably blocked because they are unencrypted (HTTP) on an encrypted site (HTTPS). You can solve that by using protocol relative URLs:

```
<script src=”//ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
```

Note the `//` instead of `http://` or `https://`. This will cause your assets to be fetched using the same protocol as the site.

Laravel has a helper function for secure assets: `secure_asset()`
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-secure-asset